# Is there a way to shutdown and start an AWS redshift cluster with the cli?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cli

I'm just bringing up a redshift cluster to start a development effort and usually use a cron service to bring down all of my development resources outside of business hours to save money.

As I browse the aws cli help:

```
aws redshift help
```

I don't see any options to stop or shutdown my test cluster like I have in the console.

If there is no way to do this, does anybody know why they don't offer this functionality?  These instances are pretty spendy to keep online and I don't want to have to go in and shut them down by hand every night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for:

- [delete-cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/delete-cluster.html), that explicitly specifies a final snapshot
- [restore-from-cluster-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/restore-from-cluster-snapshot.html), restoring the snapshot taken above

From the aws-cli `aws redshift delete-cluster` [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/delete-cluster.html):

> If you want to shut down the cluster and retain it for future use, set
>   *SkipFinalClusterSnapshot* to "false" and specify a name for
>   *FinalClusterSnapshotIdentifier* . You can later restore this snapshot to resume using the cluster. If a final cluster snapshot is requested,
>   the status of the cluster will be "final-snapshot" while the snapshot
>   is being taken, then it's "deleting" once Amazon Redshift begins
>   deleting the cluster.

Example usage, again from the documentation:

```
# When shutting down at night...
aws redshift delete-cluster --cluster-identifier mycluster --final-cluster-snapshot-identifier my-snapshot-id

# When starting up in the morning...
aws redshift restore-from-cluster-snapshot --cluster-identifier mycluster --snapshot-identifier my-snapshot-id
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  I guess that makes sense since the storage appears to be ephemeral.